# A question related to period of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations

Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. I want to find if there exists a triplet $(c,A,b)$ such that:
\begin{align*}
c^Tb=1&,      c^T A^3 b=1, &\ldots \\
c^TAb=0&,     c^T A^4 b=0,& \ldots\\
c^T A^2 b=0&, c^T A^5 b=0, & \ldots \\
\end{align*}
In otherwords, $c^TA^{n}b=1$ whenever $n(\mod 3)=0$ and $0$ otherwise. I strongly feel that there doesn't exist any such triplet but unable to provide a proof. The reason I feel this way is because I think somehow $A$ should be related to permutation matrices and a $2 \times 2$ permutation matrix can only have period $2$.

Can anyone suggest me a way to approach this problem? For the sake of simplicity I assumed that both $c=b=[1 \ 0]^T$. Then the question is equiavalent to asking does there exist a matrix $A$ such that $(A^n)_{11}=1$ when $n(\mod{3})=0$. But this doesn't seem to help in solving the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would not be enough to prove the statement for $c = b = [1 \;0]^T$.  It would be enough, however, to prove the statement for $c = [1 \;0]^T$.

Comment: Why can we assume that $c=[1\ 0]^T$ without loss of generality? Because of rotational symmetry?

Comment: Select an invertible $P$ such that $c^T P = [1 \;0]^T$.  Then if $B = P^{-1}AP$, we have
$$
c^TA^n b = (c^T P) B^n (P^{-1}b) = [1 \; 0]^T B^n (P^{-1}b)
$$
If your $P$ is a rotation, then this is indeed an argument by rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$Ab, A^2b \in C=\{ b \in \mathbb R^2 \mid c^Tb = 0 \}$$ since $C$ is 1-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb R$, vector $A^2b = \lambda Ab$. But then, $$A^3b = A(A^2b)=\lambda A^2b \in C$$, which means that $c^t A^3b=0$.

Comment: I think the fact that $c \neq 0$ is implicit in the above argument though it's obvious from the question.

Comment: Yes, if $c=0$ then $C=\mathbb R^2$ but again $c^T A^3b=0$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no: suppose that $c^TAb = c^TA^2b = 0$.  Then $Ab$ is perpendicular to $c$, and so is $A^2b$.  In two dimensions, this means that $A^2b$ is **a multiple** of $Ab$, which is to say that $A(Ab) = \lambda Ab$.

It would follow that for $k \geq 2$, we have $A^kb = A^{k-1}(Ab) = \lambda^{k-1}b$, which implies that $c^TA^kb = 0$ for $k \geq 2$.

---

As for the generalization:  Suppose $A$ is $n \times n$, and $0 = c^TAb = c^TA^2b = \cdots = c^TA^{n}b$.  Let $S$ denote the span of $\{Ab,A^2b,\dots,A^{n}b\} \subset c^\perp$.  By the Cayley-Hamitlon theorem, we have
$$
A^{n+1}b = A^{n}Ab = (d_0 I + d_1A + \cdots + d_{n-1}A^{n-1})Ab \in S
$$
$A^{n+1}b \in S \subset \{c\}^\perp$, so $c^TA^{n+1}b = 0$.

Comment: We can generalize this to higher dimensions using the same argument right? I mean a $3 \times 3$ matrix can not have period $4$ in the above sense. Is this correct?

Comment: I was just wondering about that.  It is not immediately clear to me that this should be the case.

Comment: It seems we can generalize this after all

Comment: What's the procedure? There needs to be some case by case analysis done it seems. You can edit your answer to include the generalization as well. I would be glad to see that.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: A note regarding the title, however: a $2 \times 2$ matrix can have *any* period, since it suffices to take a suitable rotation matrix.

Comment: Correct. A small extension: The answer would be yes if we allow the order of the matrix to be $n+1$ right? Do you have a specific matrix in mind that achieves this?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon I assume that by order you mean size.  In this case, yes. Let $A$ be the "cyclic" permutation matrix, so $A^{n+1} = I$.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: I upvoted it unknowingly while scrolling down the page.